# webdriver - Setting a proxy for IE in C#

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, selenium, webdriver

Is it possible to set a proxy programatically in webdriver for IE?
For Chrome, I do something like this:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
proxy.HttpProxy = "http://proxy.com:8080";
proxy.SslProxy = "http://proxy.com:8080";
options.AddAdditionalCapability("proxy", proxy);
```

but this doesn't work for IE. I've also tried: `options.AddAdditionalCapability(CapabilityType.Proxy, proxy);` which doesn't work. Is there a comparable capability for IE?

Comment: Seems like the answer is no. Is there a way to do this programatically outside of webdriver? Messing around with the registry seems like overkill. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the latest IEDriverServer (version 2.34.0.0)?  This is feature is very new to the IEDriverServer.  The .NET bindings now expose the Proxy via the InternetExplorerOptions class.

This is the change log:  https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/detail?r=084758c6b515a2699b82c6bf5871e29b552cbc8f

You should be able to do the exact same thing now after updating the IEDriverServer and .NEt bindings:

```cs
InternetExplorerOptions options = new InternetExplorerOptions();
Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
proxy.HttpProxy = "http://proxy.com:8080";
proxy.SslProxy = "http://proxy.com:8080";
options.Proxy = proxy;
```

Answer (score 0):

String PROXY = url://login:pass@proxy:port";
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

```
    options.AddArguments("user-data-dir=path/in/your/system");

    Proxy proxy = new Proxy();

    proxy.HttpProxy = PROXY;
    proxy.SslProxy  = PROXY;
    proxy.FtpProxy  = PROXY;

    options.Proxy = proxy;

    // Initialize the Chrome Driver
    using (var driver = new ChromeDriver(options))
```